# Conditional subquery that returns a running total

Tags: sql-server, database

I am trying to run a subquery with a condition that returns a running total. However, I am receiving the following error:

> Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the subquery is not introduced with EXISTS.

Is there any way this code can be salvaged?  Please be aware this code is part of a larger script that executes perfectly.  The reason I need to keep it in this format is because it is the "missing piece", for lack of a better word.

```
SELECT A.[WeekEnding], 
    (
    SELECT SUM(A.[Weekly Sales Units]), A.[Description], A.[WeekEnding]
    FROM [FACT_SALES_HISTORY] A 
    INNER JOIN [DIM_DATE] B
    ON A.WeekEnding = B.[WeekEnding] WHERE B.[YA Latest 1 Week] = 1 
    GROUP BY A.[Description], A.[WeekEnding]
    ) AS 'YA Units'
FROM [FACT_SALES_HISTORY] A 
LEFT JOIN [DIM_DATE] B
ON A.WeekEnding = B.[WeekEnding]
```

The output data, from the code, would look like the following:

```
 [Weekly Sales Units])  A.[Description]  A.[WeekEnding]
   24                   Item One          03-10-2010
   55                   Item Two          03-10-2010
   79                   Item One          03-10-2010
   98                   Item Five         03-10-2010
   11                   Item Five         03-10-2010
```

Comment: Please give sample data and results.

Comment: Thank you.  I have added sample data and results.

Comment: I'm not sure what the "outer" query is doing, can you just use the subquery?

Comment: I plan to include more columns in the "outer" query once I figure this out.

Comment: Does the table "Fact_Sales_History" have a primary key?

Comment: There is no primary key

Comment: It looks like your subquery on its own would provide the sample data and the outer query is trying to sum that up by weekending.  Is that what you are trying to do?

Comment: Thanks for sample data. What do you expect as a result of your query?

Comment: Thank you. Please see the revised original post.

Comment: Not clear and you cannot use that format.  The select needs to return a single value.

Answer (score 1):

You can't select three different items in your subquery and then use an AS assignment.  You could split that into two separate queries and then union them.

```
SELECT SUM(A.[Weekly Sales Units]), A.[Description], A.[WeekEnding]
    FROM [FACT_SALES_HISTORY] A 
    INNER JOIN [DIM_DATE] B
    ON A.WeekEnding = B.[WeekEnding] WHERE B.[YA Latest 1 Week] = 1 
    GROUP BY A.[Description], A.[WeekEnding]
UNION ALL -- This will only union distinct columns
SELECT A.[WeekEnding]...<Your other columns>
    FROM [FACT_SALES_HISTORY] A
```

Answer (score -1):

t looks like your subquery on its own would provide the sample data and the outer query is trying to sum that up by weekending.  If that is the case, then the whole thing could be replaced with this:

```
SELECT A.[WeekEnding], SUM(A.[Weekly Sales Units]) [YA Units]
FROM [FACT_SALES_HISTORY] A 
INNER JOIN [DIM_DATE] B
ON A.WeekEnding = B.[WeekEnding] WHERE B.[YA Latest 1 Week] = 1 
GROUP BY A.[WeekEnding]
```

Comment: thanks, but this part of a larger script that must be solved